# Пауза между скриптами

Tags: javascript, асинхронность, promise

есть 2 скрипта асинхронных, запускается первый и дальше ничего не происходит, второй не запускается, просто висит.В чем проблема?

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const addOrdersToGoogleSheets = async statuses => {
  console.log("addOrdersToGoogleSheets", statuses) 
};

await promisify(addOrdersToGoogleSheets)([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
await promisify(addOrdersToGoogleSheets)(12);
```

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужно использовать `promisify`, т.к. у вас функция и так асинхронная. `promisity` создает обертку для методов, которые не работает с промисами, а со старым подходом основанным на `callback` и требует, чтобы ему передавали метод со следующей сигнатурой: `(param, callback) => {}`. Исправить это можно разными способами:
Используя сразу промисы:

```
const addOrdersToGoogleSheets = async statuses => {
  console.log("addOrdersToGoogleSheets", statuses) 
};

await addOrdersToGoogleSheets([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
await addOrdersToGoogleSheets(12);
```

Использую `promisify`:

```
const addOrdersToGoogleSheets = (statuses, callback) => {
  console.log("addOrdersToGoogleSheets", statuses);
  if (callback)
    callback();
};

await promisify(addOrdersToGoogleSheets)([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
await promisify(addOrdersToGoogleSheets)(12);
```

В данном случае `callback` нужен для того, чтобы понять когда оригинальный метод завершился и можно сделать `Promise.resolve()`, чтобы вызывающий код мог понять, что промис завершился, поэтому у вас и не вызывается второй часть кода, т.к. по факту первый промис никогда не завершается.

`promisity` внутри работает примерно так (это не настоящий исходный код):

```
function primisity(fn) {
    return function (...args) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            fn(...args, resolve); // тут и передается функция resolve в качестве callback
        });
    };
};
```